# How to avoid list index out of range in Django ORM query

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a tricky scenario here ,usually I get 6 values from the below query , basically prices at start and month end of the month, prices value will be there every time

```
trade_date price
01-01-2021 120.2
31-01-2021 220.2
01-02-2021 516.2
28-02-2021 751.0
01-03-2021 450.2
31-03-2021 854.9
```

and I need Sum of 1st month starting price + 1st month Ending price + every months ending price
ie 120.2+220.2+751.0+854.9
but in some cases, last month data tend to miss, how to handle those scenarios

```
monthly_values = Items.objects.filter(trade_date__gte=quarter_start_date,
                          trade_date__lte=quarter_end_date).values_list('price',
                          flat=True).order_by('trade_date')
 
total_sum = monthly_values[0]+monthly_values[1]+monthly_values[3]+monthly_values[5])
```

Currently getting list index out of range from the above because of missing values

Comment: If your problem is as it is portrayed in your code, then use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) instead of indexing it manually

Comment: if do the sum all the values will be captured , I need to omit the  2nd  and 3rd  months starting value

Comment: Ah gotcha, I should've read your question more clearly. Is the data static, or dynamic and your requirement is: 1.Start at first month starting price, 2. skip all other month's starting prices 3.only add every month's ending price ?

Comment: @AsgerWeirsøe for the first month staring date price  and end date  price , for remaining month's only last date price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it has been some time since I last used DjangoORM, but you can do something similarly to this

```py
from datetime import date

monthly_values: list[tuple[date, float]] = Items.objects.filter(trade_date__gte=quarter_start_date,
                          trade_date__lte=quarter_end_date).values_list('trade_date', 'price').order_by('trade_date')
```

Then create a function that adds the starting price from our input to a result, and afterwards add all prices where it is not the first day of the month.

```py
def get_prices(month_and_prices: list[tuple[date, float]]) -> float:
    res = month_and_prices[0][1]
    res += sum([x[1] for x in month_and_prices[1:] if x[0].day > 1])
    return res
```

This should solve what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the line and then the column:

```
total_sum = 0
for i in [0, 1, 3, 5]:    
    total_sum += monthly_values[i][1]
```

This gives you access "by hand". @Asger 's answer is automated.

Comment: getting the below error AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'iat'